# Average Cells of Two or More DataFrames

Tags: r

So I currently have 3 data frames that I need to average each cell in, and I am at a loss of how to do this... Essentially, I need to obtain the mean of the first observation in column 1 for df1, df2, df3, and like that for every single observation.

Here is a reproducible sample data.

```
set.seed(789)
df1 <-   data.frame(
a = runif(100, 0, 100),
b = runif(100, 0, 100),
c = runif(100, 0, 100),
d = runif(100, 0, 100))

df2 <-   data.frame(
a = runif(100, 0, 100),
b = runif(100, 0, 100),
c = runif(100, 0, 100),
d = runif(100, 0, 100))

df3 <-   data.frame(
a = runif(100, 0, 100),
b = runif(100, 0, 100),
c = runif(100, 0, 100),
d = runif(100, 0, 100))
```

I need to create a fourth data frame of dimensions 100 by 4 that is the result of averaging each cell across the first three dataframes. Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: `(df1+df2+df3)/3`

Comment: It would need a `set.seed` statement at the beginning tob e reproducible;; otherwise, each person copying and pasting it will up with different values for df1, df2 and df3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this with `Reduce` with `+` and divide by the number of datasets in a `list`.  This has the flexibility of keeping 'n' number of datasets in a `list`

```
dfAvg <- Reduce(`+`, mget(paste0("df", 1:3)))/3
```

---

Or another option is to convert to `array` and then use `apply`, which also have the option of removing the missing values (`na.rm=TRUE`)

```
apply(array(unlist(mget(paste0("df", 1:3))), c(dim(df1), 3)), 2, rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
```

As @user20650 mentioned, `rowMeans` can be applied directly on the `array` with the `dim`

```
rowMeans(array(unlist(mget(paste0("df", 1:3))), c(dim(df1), 3)), dims=2)
```

Comment: `L = mget(ls(pattern = "df\\d+")); dfAvg = Reduce("+", L)/length(L)`

Comment: The Reduce command works great. I have a question... Is it possible to get Reduce to ignore some rows in the df? I just realized that my original DF has two columns that are ID variables that are factors and need to be ignored in the calculation of the averages. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @rowbust In that case you can subset the dataset and place it in the `list` i.e. For example, if the ID variables are the 1st and 2nd columns and want to remove it `lst <- list(df1[-(1:2)], df2[-(1:2)], df3[-(1:2)]); dfAvg <- Reduce("+", lst)/3` assuming that the ID variables are the same across all the datasets.  This can be automated as well (depends on your needs)